# Digitally sign all outbound data

Tags: digital-signature

I want to digitally sign all outbound data from my computer. Can someone suggest a way to do this programatically or using some tool? Instead of actually signing the data, I would simply append a small random string at the end. (It's the same thing as long as website doesn't care about signatures. Unless I am wrong.)

I want to see websites' response to signed data with funky tails when they do not expect it. This is important aspect of an experimental protocol that I am working on. I would like to see if it breaks my internet or the websites simply ignore it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I know you are working on a protocol.  Can you clean up your question a bit, there are some gaps that are in your head, which you've not communicated ... would make it a lot easier to help you.  What do you mean outbound messages? Are you talking about e-mail or are you talking about another serialization scenario.  Do you have control of the web site in question?  If not, I don't think anyone could say for certain which websites are going to react to extraneous data or not.

Comment: You want to sign messages or packets?

Comment: Sorry about confusing terminology. I want to digitally sign EVERYTHING that goes out of my computer to internet. Call it packet or message or frame whichever appropriate. Just want to know how can I do this.

I do not have control over target websites. I just want to see whether they mind it or not. I am considering all kinds of websites. Simple html pages to google and facebook.

Comment: Whoa, @Xovie. You just made this question nonsensical. Tell us you understand protocols and that you understand the concept of a stack.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for the feeback :). Apparently I am not good with terminology. PLease refer to the answer below. That should make question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scope of this question is a little too broad...

Do you have any idea how many packets must be leaving your computer right now, just by browsing stack exchange?! If not, I suggest you download wireshark and monitor your own network card, you might be surprised!

I think this is actually an interesting experiment, but you'll have to do it in small chunks. Instead of adding 'some random data' to all packets, how about just trying against one site or application?

I would be wary of just doing it without letting people know though, as it may be viewed as malicious communications. It might be best at first to have your own web server with a simple page or pages and try and interact with it, watching the packets in wireshark. Once you understand what's going on, try and write an equivalent using Python in something like scapy, and see if your local web server responds in the same way

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I was thinking of putting up a small website and testing its response. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xovie I thought your question was about how to add a Digital Sig, not how to test web server response.

Comment: That's the goal. Once I add the signature, I want to observe how server responds to that. So first step is to add a signature and then wait and watch.

Comment: @Xovie your WHOLE QUESTION is about "adding the signature". How is this answer satisfactory?